# Show Message Box when application is in background

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I need to show a Message box for user with two buttons(open application, cancel) when an application is in background. How can I realise it (should it be a background task) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't show custom message box from background.

As a workaround you can show `Toast Notification` from `Background Agent`. Look at [`ShellToast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), it's made for this purpose. When toast appears, users can tap it to open application as you need.

Comment: I know how use Toast Notification when application is closed. But how can I implement it when it is in background ?

Comment: Good tutorial with `Notifications` from `Background Agent`: http://wildermuth.com/2011/09/06/Periodic_Agents_on_Windows_Phone_7_1

Comment: @revolutionkpi, when your application is in the background (i.e. another app or the Start screen is in the foreground) it is dormant so can't do anything.  An app can continue running under the lock screen if configured to do so but that is different (it's still in the foreground, just covered by the lock screen).